# Java library cant resolve package

Tags: java, package, libraries

I added a library with several packages one of which is "no.stelar7.api.r4j.impl.lor". When I go to import this package to use it in my code I am given an error saying it can't be resolved, I have tried deleting the library and re-importing it with no luck and need any help. There is another package in the library called "no.stelar7.api.r4j.impl", is it possible this is causing me errors?

Comment: how do you import libs? do you use maven/gradle?

Comment: Yeah, I also think that the issue is that he did not add dependencies to the Gradle (or Maven).

Answer (score 0):

Check if the library available for your current java version

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).